# Problems with "document.write" using RequireJS modules

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs

I have a module that needs to execute a document.write action in order to print a banner once the page is loaded.

If I do this using the old-school way, I get no problems.
The banner is printed inside the div.

```
<div id="banner">
    <script> addAdvert() </script>
</div>

<script>
function addAdvert(){
  srcScript = 'http://www.urltoscript.js';
  document.write('<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"'+srcScript+'" ><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

But If I try this using a require js module (kind of this):

```
addAvert: function() {
             var srcScript = options.urltoScript
             document.write('<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"'+srcScript+'" ><\/script>');
}
```

It executes the document.write and render all the document printing only the banner on the entire document...

I have try this alternative:

```
addAvert: function() {
    var srcScript = options.urltoScript

          var bsa = document.createElement('script');
             bsa.type = 'text/javascript';
             bsa.async = true;
             bsa.src = srcScript;
             $("#banner").append(bsa);
 }
```

Comment: You really want to avoid using `document.write` at all if you can help it.

Comment: Yes, sure...but how I have try the second alternative, it writes the <script> tag an all that stuff but it does'nt perform the script itself –

Comment: By adding `<script>` tags yourself (either through `document.write`, or `document.createElement`) you're forfeiting the benefits of RequireJS as a loader. Your urltoscript.js should be turned into an AMD module so it can be loaded via `require('urltoscript.js')`. It may be useful to include example code of such an "advert" popup.

Comment: That was a goo one...but when I put this
`require([bsa.src])`
I get this message:
`Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your comment, the script which you are trying to load from the imaginary URL `http://www.urltoscript.js` *also* uses `document.write`. Either you should change this script to not use `document.write` or you should abandon the idea of loading it asynchronously, because **`document.write` does not work reliably when invoked asynchronously**.

You've already discovered when you tried `require([bsa.src])` (as you mentioned in a comment) that you cannot call `document.write` from a script that is loaded asynchronously. (Also note that just doing `require([bsa.src])` is not going to work unless the source code at the other end is an AMD-module or you defined a `shim` for it.)

Your first attempt at loading through RequireJS did not produce an error message about `document.write` being loaded asynchronously because the `script` element that loads it is not *itself* asynchronous. However, it completely blanked your page. This is because if you call `document.write` after the page has finished loading, the browser may implicitly call [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open) and this may blank your page.

The upshot here is that you cannot reliably use `document.write` with asynchronous code.